# How do I format an amount of milliseconds into minutes:seconds:milliseconds in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time-format

I have a total ammount of milliseconds (ie 70370) and I want to display it as minutes:seconds:milliseconds ie 00:00:0000.

How can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Don't fall into the trap of using date functions for this! What you have here is a time interval, not a date. The naive approach is to do something like this:

```
date("H:i:s.u", $milliseconds / 1000)
```

but because the date function is used for (gasp!) dates, it doesn't handle time the way you would want it to in this situation - it takes timezones and daylight savings, etc, into account when formatting a date/time.

Instead, you will probably just want to do some simple maths:

```
$input = 70135;

$uSec = $input % 1000;
$input = floor($input / 1000);

$seconds = $input % 60;
$input = floor($input / 60);

$minutes = $input % 60;
$input = floor($input / 60); 

// and so on, for as long as you require.
```

Comment: It would still be a hack, but you can use `gmdate()` if you are sure that your values will be less than 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PHP 5.3 you can make use of the [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) object:

```
list($seconds, $millis) = explode('.', $milliseconds / 1000);
$range = new DateInterval("PT{$seconds}S");
echo $range->format('%H:%I:%S') . ':' . str_pad($millis, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: How do you get $seconds? You have to convert $millis into $seconds, don't you?

Comment: If you use 70370 as $milliseconds here you get 00:00:70:037...shouldn't 70 seconds add 1 minute?

Comment: Crucially DateTime class doesn't carry over excess units of time, which makes it pretty useless for me. See "Creating a DateInterval Object " on http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/php-dateinterval-class/ for a note about this.

Answer (score 4):

why bother with `date()` and formatting when you can just use math ?
if `$ms` is your number of milliseconds

```
echo floor($ms/60000).':'.floor(($ms%60000)/1000).':'.str_pad(floor($ms%1000),3,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 3):

**convert milliseconds to formatted time**

```
<?php
/* Write your PHP code here */
$input = 7013512333;

$uSec = $input % 1000;
$input = floor($input / 1000);

$seconds = $input % 60;
$input = floor($input / 60);

$minutes = $input % 60;
$input = floor($input / 60);

$hour = $input ;

echo sprintf('%02d %02d %02d %03d', $hour, $minutes, $seconds, $uSec);
?>
```

check demo here : 
https://www.phprun.org/qCbY2n

Answer (score 1):

Try this function to display amount of milliseconds the way you like:

```
<?php
function udate($format, $utimestamp = null)
{
   if (is_null($utimestamp)) {
       $utimestamp = microtime(true);
   }

   $timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
   $milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000000);

   return date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', sprintf("%06u", $milliseconds), $format), $timestamp);
}

echo udate('H:i:s.u'); // 19:40:56.78128
echo udate('H:i:s.u', 654532123.04546); // 16:28:43.045460
?>
```

[Source](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#85376)

Comment: btw - I have no idea what that `preg_replace` is doing. Looks pretty odd.

Comment: I guess it just replaces u not preceded by backslash with actual number.

Comment: If I were a math teacher I would say if $utime = NULL, the $milliseconds will return a negativ value?
Why do you multiple the milliseconds with 100000 ? If you want to have seconds, minutes etc. you have to divise it.

Comment: I'd make sure the milliseconds part is formatted with leading zero's though, using something like `sprintf("%06u", $milliseconds)`, otherwise 5 milliseconds will look like 0.5

Comment: @Wim - I think you are right. Author of this code made a mistake. It's visible even in example he gave. I'm correcting this answer accordingly to your comment to avoid misleading future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the manual:

> u     Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2) 
>     Example: 654321

We have a 'u' parameter for the date() function

Example:

```
if(($u/60) >= 60)
{
$u = mktime(0,($u / 360));
}
date('H:i:s',$u);
```

Answer (score 0):

no, you can use CarbonInterval:

```
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;
...
$actualDrivingTimeString = CarbonInterval::seconds($milliseconds/1000)
  ->cascade()->format('%H:%I:%S');
...
```

voila, and you are done