# Convert hundredths to "minutes:seconds.hundredths" in PHP

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format an amount of milliseconds into minutes:seconds:milliseconds in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833869/how-do-i-format-an-amount-of-milliseconds-into-minutessecondsmilliseconds-in-p)

In PHP, I need help to convert a string with hundredths to "minutes:seconds.hundredths".

So for example if I have this: '10420' and want to display it like this: 01:44.20.

I played a bit with php date() but I couldn't get it to work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can find answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833869/how-do-i-format-an-amount-of-milliseconds-into-minutessecondsmilliseconds-in-p

Comment: Play with the `u` part of date() perhaps? That does microseconds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this (should be self-explanatory):

```
$hundreds = 10420;
$secs = intval($hundreds / 100);
$frac = $hundreds - $secs * 100;
echo gmdate("i:s", $secs).sprintf(".%02d", $frac), "\n";
```

Your requirements are funny, because it looks like you want to ignore the hours part.
You can still add it back with `gmdate("H:i:s", $secs)`, if you want. Of course, also this works well only up to 24h.

Comment: I accually don't need to show hours. Thanks, works great!

Answer (score 3):

Uh, what's wrong with simple mathematics on the date?

```
$start=10420;//Or whatever... your example value
$hs=$start%100;//Hundredths
$start-=$hs;
$m=floor($start/6000);//Minutes
$start-=$m*6000;
$s=$start/100;//Seconds

echo "It's $m:$s.$hs;"
```

Obviously that's better written in a function... but you get the idea.

Comment: just one problem: when `$hs < 10`

Comment: works great except when $hs < 10 as stated. If you have 1104 hundredths, it displays 00:11.4 instead of 00:11.04

Comment: It works absolutely fine, even when `$hs` is less than ten.  Sure the `echo` statement doesn't zero buffer like the original request, but it was just for a quick example... all three values (`$m`, `$s`, `$hs`) need to be zero buffered with sprintf or strpad, but the correct value for `$hs` is still 4 (integer) not 04 (string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes in these code:

```
$start=10420;//Or whatever... your example value
$hs=$start%100;//Hundredths
$start-=$hs;
$m=floor($start/6000);//Minutes
$start-=$m*6000;
$s=$start/100;//Seconds
$m = sprintf("%02s",$m);

echo "It's $m:$s:$hs";
```